# Understanding Pivot Spaces in PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Suppose two (separable) Hilbert spaces $(X_1, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_1)$ and $(X_2, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_2)$ are embedded continuously and densely, i.e. $X_1 \subseteq X_2$ and $\| x \|_2 \leq C \| x \|_1$ $\forall x \in X_1$. This arises e.g. in elliptic PDEs when $X_1 = H^1_0(\Omega), X_2 = L^2(\Omega)$. Suppose to have an orthonormal basis $(e_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $X_1$ which is also orthogonal in $X_2$ (these are, e.g. eigenfunctions of elliptic operators). Would like to show that $(e_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is also complete in $X_2$.
My reasoning was the following: take any $u \in X_2$ such that $\langle u, e_k \rangle_2 = 0\;\, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then we know that $u \in X_2 = (X_2)^{*} \subseteq (X_1)^{*}$ with duality pearing given by $\langle u, w \rangle_{X_1^*, X_1} := \langle u, w \rangle_{2}$ for any $w \in X_1$. But since $(e_k)$ form a basis of $X_1$, $\langle u, e_k \rangle_{X_1^*, X_1} = 0\;\, \forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ implies $u = 0$ in $X_1^{*}$. Now to conclude that $u = 0$ in $X_2$, I could use the Riesz representation to get $u = 0$ in $X_1$, but this is somewhat scary because when we use reasonings such as $ X_1 \subseteq X_2 = (X_2)^* \subseteq (X_1)^{*} $, we don't want to identify $X_1$ with its dual (I read this somewher in Chapter 5 of the book by Brezis). Am I doing some mistake? Is there some alternative approach?

Answer (score 1):

If $u\in X_2$ is orthogonal to all $e_k\in X_1$ in the $X_2$ inner product,
then $u$ is orthogonal to all of $X_1$.
This is a consequence of the continuity of the embedding.
Since $X_1$ is dense in $X_2$, its orthogonal complement in $X_2$ is equal to $\{0\}$, hence $u=0$.

Comment: In your example, $X_1$ does not seem to be dense in $X_2$.

Comment: @gerw edited. I missed the density assumption.